# Select row based on values in associated rows in EAV

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (EAV relationship), `Customer` (`id`,`name`) and `CustomerVarchar` (`id`,`customer_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`) with relationships below.

`Customer` hasMany `CustomerVarchar`

`CustomerVarchar` belongsTo `Customer`

I'd like to select a row in `Customer` based on two rows with specific values in `CustomreVarchar`. More specifically, I want to retrieve a row in `Customer` that has these two associated rows with the below condition (must have both of the associated rows in `CustomerVarchar`):

```
row 1 has `attribute_id`= 5 and `value`=`John`

row 2 has `attribute_id`= 7 and `value`=`Doe`
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to return the `customer_id` from the `customerVarchar` table with all of the attributes and values:

```
select customer_id
from customerVarchar
group by customer_id
having 
  sum(case when attribute_id = 5 and value = 'John' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when attribute_id = 7 and value = 'Doe' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Then you can JOIN this to your `customer` table to return the customers with that data:

```
select c.id, c.name
from customer c
inner join
(
  select customer_id
  from customerVarchar
  group by customer_id
  having 
    sum(case when attribute_id = 5 and value = 'John' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    and sum(case when attribute_id = 7 and value = 'Doe' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
) v
  on c.id = v.customer_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12d35/4)

Comment: Thanks BF! Two things. 1: in the 1st query, why do you utilize the `sum(case when... then 1...) > 1` method? Is it because I need to check for 4 matching values over 2 rows? 2: I noticed that in the `CASE` statement following `HAVING`, you can't use the table name to precede the column name, but you can if the `HAVING` clause if  `CASE` is not present. Is this right?

Comment: @Youn Yes, I used a `HAVING` clause with the SUM because you want 4 values over two rows.  If you wanted just two values, then I would use a `WHERE`/`GROUP BY` clause with a `HAVING count(distinct..)`.  I am not sure I understand your second question though.